# Google Sign In with firebase in ionic 3 or 4 - Platform Android

Tags: android, firebase, ionic3, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to build a google sign in and authentication using Firebase and ionic. But when trying to run the application on the Android emulator. It gives me the following error.

***Type Error object(...) is not a function***

Following Code Im Using

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

  //Method For Identify the Platform
  googleLogin() {
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      this.nativeGoogleLogin();
    }
    else {
      this.webGoogleLogin();
    }
  }

  //Method For Native Google Login
  async nativeGoogleLogin() : Promise<firebase.User>{
    try {

      const gplusUser = await this.gplus.login({
        'webClientId': 'WebClienId.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'offline': true,
        'scopes': 'profile email'
      })

      return await this.fireauth.auth.signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken))

    }
    catch (error) {
      this.showSuccessAlert('Native Error',error)
    }
  }
```